# fileExistsAtPath: returning NO for files that exist

Tags: ios

At a point in my code fileExistsAtPath: is returning NO for files that I have confirmed exist. I've been scratching my head at this and can't figure out why its not working, so changed it to this code as this directory absolutely exists but if it doesn't gets created anyway.

```
NSError* err = nil;
NSURL *dir = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
                                                       inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                              appropriateForURL:nil   
                                                         create: YES
                                                          error:&err];
BOOL exists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[dir absoluteString]];
```

After running this code the application directory folder exists and err is 0, yet exists is NO.

How can this be?

TIA

Comment: You're also not checking if the URLForDirectory... method returns nil.

Comment: Further, the documentation doesn't indicate whether the create action is synchronous or asynchronous, but try sticking in a delay of a few seconds before your fileExistsAtPath: call and see if the result changes.

Comment: Err is nil as I mentioned. Also dir is being populated correctly with the path of the directory (if I po it in the console or NSLog it, its contents are set correctly). The directory already exists anyway before I call this code  - if I run the app twice fore example I still get that the exists BOOL is being set to 0.

Comment: Why are you using [dir absoluteString] and not [dir path]?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You should use `[dir path]`, not `[dir absoluteString]`.

Comment: Can you please note what is the mf difference that made me waste an hour or so debugging my code?

Comment: path returns a regular path. absoluteString returns a file:/// url as a string.  `(lldb) print fileURL.path
(String!) $R0 = "/Users/joshwisenbaker/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4ED0C33D-A9AB-49EF-9AD3-13396E7C3CCA/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/D2180E2E-A409-430E-AC47-C71353547417/jobs.plist"
(lldb) print fileURL.absoluteString
(String!) $R1 = "file:///Users/joshwisenbaker/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4ED0C33D-A9AB-49EF-9AD3-13396E7C3CCA/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/D2180E2E-A409-430E-AC47-C71353547417/jobs.plist"`

Comment: i am using path, still it is returning false everytime

Answer (score 6):

I was bashing my head against the wall for a few hours. Apparently on each and every run in xcode (on simulator) the app directory path was changing. The UUID part of it.
So instead of storing the fullpath I ended up persisting the path postfix
and prefixing that with whatever storage class is implied: temporary, cached
or documents :-[ You realize why you have to sometimes run on device
even if you don't explore the depths of Metal, GLES or multitouch? ;^)

Answer (score 5):

There is a distinction between path and url.  A path in unix representation is the location where your particular file or directory exists. Like `"/Users/username/Desktop/myfile.txt"`

Wheres a url not only contains the location but scheme as well, e.g: http:// or https:// and in our case a file url `(file:///Users/username/Desktop/myfile.txt)`

Methods like `fileExistsAtPath` or `removeItemAtPath` need path in the parameter rather than a url.

While methods like `copyItemAtURL:toURL:error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error` expects a url.

Use `path` attribute of `NSURL` object to retrieve the path. `absoluteString` gives you the path along with the scheme.