# Downloaded file does not exist

Tags: ios, objective-c

I download a file in the background by using [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-background-transfer-service--mobile-20595)

When the file is downloaded, there are 2 functions informing us. I write them in order of time happening:

**1)**  `- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)downloadURL;`

**2)** `- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error;`

In the function 1, I check the downloaded file still exists.

In the function 2, I check the downloaded file does not exists. I think it is deleted by the iOS system.

Could you explain for me why?
Thanks

Comment: Where did you get the downloaded file path?

Comment: Did you check the file path is exists in finder?

Comment: @trick14: so what is the proper Document path in this case?

Comment: Check this [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Comment: @grhnkdlk: I check it in the simulator, and there is no file. So, I am wondering where my file is located after it is downloaded.

Comment: so your problem is there is no file path such that. Update your question with your download code snippet then we can help

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will update my question in few minutes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
      downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
```

According to [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate/URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:) :

> session: The session containing the download task that finished.
>
> downloadTask: The download task that finished.
>
> location : A file URL for the temporary file. Because the file is temporary, you must either open the file for reading or move it to a permanent location in your app’s sandbox container directory before returning from this delegate method.
>   If you choose to open the file for reading, you should do the actual reading in another thread to avoid blocking the delegate queue.

So yes that *downloaded file* **temporary**. If you want to keep your downloaded files in your app you should save this data under `NSDocuments` path.

more info [ray wenderlich's blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial)

> When the task is finished, URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL: is called. This is when you can save the file from the temp location to a permanent one.

When you are in this method write downloaded data to your folder. But do not block thread.

Comment: Do I need to create another thread to copy the temporary downloaded file to my app's sandbox? (in the case the temporary file's size is big)

Comment: yes you should create another thread to copy process. This is must be async task :)

Comment: Creating another thread (async task)  to copy is wrong, because at the end of this method (URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
      downloadTask ....) the temporary file is deleted. This method is trying to delete the file while our thread is trying to copy.

Comment: @chipbk10 [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60255581/700471) of copying the temporary file from a background thread.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

Try using `[downloadURL path]` instead of `[downloadURL absoluteString]` in your call to `fileExistsAtPath:`

like so

```
BOOL exist1 = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[downloadURL path]];
```

See [fileExistsAtPath: returning NO for files that exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303875/fileexistsatpath-returning-no-for-files-that-exist) for more :-)

Comment: No, it's not my problem. Please see my updated question.

Comment: A year...thats quite a long time :) glad you got it working

Answer (score 1):

Try to copy the file content in the same thread.

```
AudioPlayerViewController: UIViewController, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDataDelegate, URLSessionDownloadDelegate{

var defaultSession: URLSession!
    var downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask!

func downloadFunc()
{
                defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
                downloadTask = defaultSession.downloadTask(with: audioUrl)
                downloadTask.resume()
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64,

 totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.downloadProgressBar.setProgress(Float(totalBytesWritten)/Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite), animated: true)

        let progressValue = Int(100 * totalBytesWritten / totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
        self.downloadProgressLabel.text = "\(progressValue)%"
    }
}
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        do {
            let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

            let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("destination_path.mp3")

            // after downloading your file you need to move it to your destination url
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: location, to: destinationUrl)
            print("File moved to documents folder")

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

}
```

Comment: More detail would make this a better answer.  How should they do that?  Why does that answer their question as to why they are seeing the behavior they are seeing?

Comment: Updated new answer.

Comment: The copyItem function helped me with my issue :) took me hours, thanks to you and your solution, Krishna.

Answer (score 0):

In the [link provided by you](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-background-transfer-service--mobile-20595) they are saving the file in the document directory so you can check the same in the iOS simulator by an NSLog statement for the variable **destinationURL** given in the [sample link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-background-transfer-service--mobile-20595) that should help you out.

```
NSLog(@"my doc directory path = %@",destinationURL);
```